# Why does my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop crash often?

Tags: dual-boot, crash

I've dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu and have been using it for the most part for the past 6 months I'm facing a few issues :

1. My Laptop crashes most often when battery is low.I assume its a hardware problem I often hear loud fan noises too
2. I checked into my Hard disks status and found this:
   Disk is OK, 609 bad sectors (40° C / 104° F)
   How do I resolve this issue?I know I'll have to backup as soon as possible.
   Model : ST1000LM035-1RK172 (LCM2)
   Size : 1.0 TB (10,00,20,48,86,016 bytes)
   RAM : 8 GB

Comment: this is way too little information,please take a look in the sysem logs and copy and paste what happens before and during the crash.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, one thing I am certain, you need a room air-circulator or room fan and lift your laptop one inch from where it is placed now. Then send cool air on the bottom of it. That will solve most of the problem you are facing.